# Using LED driver to control heater

Tags: dc-dc-converter, led-driver, heater

currently, I have a 24V 150W heater and I would like to see the feasibility of using LED driver for controlling the heater. My input voltage is 48VDC

The reason for this is that some LED drivers I have looked at utilize external MOSFETs and passives to meet the power required by the heater (such as LM3409HV, LT3756,...) Instead of having to source a DC-DC converter, I would have this one integrated in the LED driver.  In addition, they do have the analog dim pin which I believe could be used for temperature control with a thermistor, similar to thermal foldback application in LED driver. Obviously, the temperature control would not be precise but it is tolerable in my design.

Here is an example of what I have in mind:
[image]
Edit: My goal is to have a passive control heater (i.e no mcu is involved in the temperature regulation). I know we can use a comparator circuit to drive a transistor to the heater as shown. However, the potentially nice thing about LED driver is that, it would incorporate all those features into one IC i.e Voltage step-down, temperature control with analog dimming. Thus, I would like too the feasibility of this concept!
[image: Heater control using comparator]

Comment: Questions asking for opinions are off-topic for this site.

Comment: "Obviously, the temperature control would not be precise" that's not at all obvious.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The LED driver use an analog voltage (V_CTRL) to control the current to the output. There is a cut off voltage such that when V_CTRL > V_CUTOFF,  the current output is independent of V_CTRL and at max. When V_CTRL < V_CUTOFF, its output will be linearly proportional to V_CTRL. Thus, we can use a voltage divider circuit with a thermistor to feed in this V_CTRL such that at certain temperature, the current output will be limited. Thus, we only know the cutoff temperature when it starts limiting its output current rather than the steady state temperature.

Comment: I would ask for feasibility of this concept, would it still be allow rather than opinions? @JohnD

Comment: @DocWest Have you considered adding a 5-cent op-amp and a few parts instead of a resistor?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany  I have looked at this thermal foldback application from TI- section 6.6: https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/tiducl3 where they use non-inverting op-amp to control the cutoff temperature where the IC start limiting current so I can see the use of op-amp in this case. Is that similar to what you are suggesting?

Comment: @DocWest It's just an input, you could drive it with the most sophisticated controller you can come up with, or just a difference amplifier. Results will vary.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I see what you are saying and definitely we can come up with controller to meet the need. However, my main question about the feasibility of driving heater with led driver remain unclear. Given that LED drivers are current-control, do you think it is a good idea to control heater with current then?

Comment: @DocWest If I knew that offhand, I would provide an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: A lot depends on what supply voltage you're starting from and whether it's AC or DC.

Comment: +1... I think this is an inspired "abuse" of an LED driver, which has a good chance of turning into something worthwhile.  I hope someone picks this up and posts something inspired.

Comment: @Finbarr it would be 48VDC input. I have updated my post as well

Comment: Why not just use PWM? Most likely the 24V resistor can work fine on 48V, just use a lower PWM ratio... Input current will be worse than a buck, but it saves a lot of parts.

Comment: @bobflux Basically, I would like to have the control to be self-regulated ( no mcu required). Thus, Im not sure how to control PWM signal passively based on temperature feedback without any microcontroller. Do you have any suggestion on this? I have edited my post for further clarification.

Comment: A 24 V power supply and a no-metal thermostat?

Comment: @winny I am thinking of a PCB solution rather than using external components.

Comment: You could use a fixed PWM ratio to lower the current from the 48V supply to something safe for your heater (if needed) and then further gate the system with a regular thermostat (either mechanical or IC) that opens/closes a heater circuit based on temperature.  No MCU required.